# log equation hard to solve, logarithm with a polynomial

Tags: logarithms

I could not solve this logarithmic equation, it proved difficult to me, just hints or full solution if you can please:
$$\log_4(3\cdot4^{x+1}-8)=2x+1$$

Comment: What happens if you exponentiate both sides (with base $2$) and set $y=2^x$?

Comment: It does not have a real solution right?

Comment: Why did you suddenly change the equation?

Comment: I wanted to see if that one results in what I came to, it does not have a real solution.

Answer (score 2):

$\log_2(3\cdot2^{x+1}-4)=2x+1 \iff 6 \cdot2^x-4=2(2^x)^2.$

Let $t=2^x$. This gives $t^2-3t+2=0.$

Can you proceed ?

Answer (score 1):

We can solve this equation by bringing it to a quadratic form.
$$
\log_2(3\cdot 2^{x+1}-4)=2x+1\\
$$
$$
\Leftrightarrow 6\cdot 2^x -4=2^{2x+1}
$$
$$
\Leftrightarrow 6\cdot 2^x -4=2\cdot (2^{x})^2 
$$

Substitute z=2^x to get a quadratic equation:
$$
6\cdot z -4=2\cdot z^2 
$$
$$
\Leftrightarrow z^2 -3z+2=0
$$
with the solutions $z=1$ and $z=2$. Thus, with $z=2^x$ we get the solutions
$x=1$ and $x=0$.

As somehow the question got changed, here the solution to the new one:
$$
\log_4(3\cdot 4^{x+1}-8)=2x+1\\
$$
$$
\Leftrightarrow 12\cdot 4^x -8=4^{2x+1}
$$
$$
\Leftrightarrow 12\cdot 4^x -8=4\cdot (4^{x})^2 
$$

Substitute $z=4^x$ to get a quadratic equation:
$$
12\cdot z -8=4\cdot z^2 
$$
$$
\Leftrightarrow z^2 -3z+2=0
$$
with again the solutions $z=1$ and $z=2$. Thus, with $z=4^x$ we get the solutions
$x=0.5$ and $x=0$.

Comment: Sorry, I have edited with other values and base, it doesn't have a solution in R, right?

Comment: Try to do the same procedure yourself, now with z=4^x to get to the quadratic equation. Check if it has real solutions and you have your answer.

Comment: @Kayte If the answer is satisfactory, please accept it by clicking on the mark next to the answer. This way, others now that this question has been answered.

Answer (score 0):

$$
\log_4(3\cdot 4^{x+1}-8)=2x+1\\
$$
$$
\rightarrow 12\cdot 4^x-8=4^{2x+1}
$$
$$
\rightarrow 12\cdot 4^x -8=4\cdot (4^{x})^2 
$$

Substitute $z=4^x$ to get a quadratic equation:
$$
12\cdot z -8=4\cdot z^2 
$$
$$
\rightarrow z^2-3z+2=0
$$
Thus $z=1$, $z=2$. You can now calculate the value of x.

Comment: I am sorry but I don't feel safe to share my contact details. You can ask here itself.

Comment: No problem, that problem of surface area of right triangle prism, can you sketch the whole solution, I can not know how to solve it. By the way, this equation has a real solution

Comment: How did you get from line $12⋅z−8=4⋅z^2$ to $z^2−12z+12=0$ ? I get to $z^2-3z+2$ which has the solutions $z=2$ and $z=1$.

Comment: @Nurator I did a mistake there.

Comment: @Kayte I will try to do that in some time.

Comment: @AdityaJain I updated my solution for the new question. It HAS two solutions.

Comment: I did the same.

Comment: @Aditya, please if you can do it for now if you have time, the surface problem